# Want only 1 input. Requires many input

Tags: c

I just started learning programming in `C` and it has been loads of fun. I wanted to write a program so I can make my school work easier.

I know it's terribly inefficient. Tips with efficiency would help me, but my main problem is that when I want to enter option 3 to calculate stuff, I have to press 3 three times on the terminal window before it starts to execute.

My problem is that I just want to enter 3 once and go straight into it.

Here is the code. You should be able to read just 4 lines and understand what's going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define R 8.31
/* Using the PV = nRT formula */

int

main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    double Temperature, Pressure, Mols, Volume, Variable;
    printf("Type the number of the variable are you finding:\n 1: Temperature\n 2: Pressure\n 3: Volume\n 4: Mols\n");
    if (scanf("%lf",&Variable) == 1 && (Variable - 1 == 0)) {
        printf("Enter your Pressure in Pa: \n");
        scanf("%lf", &Pressure);
        printf("Enter your Volume in L: \n");
        scanf("%lf", &Volume);
        printf("Enter your Mols in mol: \n");
        scanf("%lf", &Mols);
        Temperature = (Pressure * Volume) / (Mols * R);
        printf("The Temperature is %.3f K (Kelvin)\n", Temperature);

    }   
    else if(scanf("%lf", &Variable) == 1 && (Variable - 2 == 0)){       
        printf("Enter your Temperature in K: \n");
        scanf("%lf", &Temperature);
        printf("Enter your Volume in L: \n");
        scanf("%lf", &Volume);
        printf("Enter your Mols in mol: \n");
        scanf("%lf",&Mols);
        Pressure = (Mols * R * Temperature)/Volume;
        printf("The Pressure is %.3f Pa (Pascals)\n", Pressure);

        }  
    else if(scanf("%lf", &Variable) == 1 && (Variable - 3 == 0)){       
        printf("Enter your Temperature in K: \n");
        scanf("%lf", &Temperature);
        printf("Enter your Pressure in Pa: \n");
        scanf("%lf", &Pressure);
        printf("Enter your Mols in mol: \n");
        scanf("%lf",&Mols);
        Volume = (Mols * R * Temperature)/Pressure;
        printf("The Volume is %.3f L (Litres)\n", Volume);

        }  
    else if(scanf("%lf", &Variable) == 1 && (Variable - 4 == 0)){       
        printf("Enter your Temperature in K: \n");
        scanf("%lf", &Temperature);
        printf("Enter your Volume in L: \n");
        scanf("%lf", &Volume);
        printf("Enter your Pressure in Pa: \n");
        scanf("%lf",&Pressure);
        Mols = (Pressure * Volume)/(R * Temperature);
        printf("The Amount of mols is %.3f mols \n", Mols);

        }  

    else {
        printf("Invalid Input, please try again\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Every `scanf` asks for input. Use it once, and then test the value of `Variable` in the `if..else` clauses. You might want to make `Variable`a simple integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you read and test the variable each time. Read the variable  once and then test it multiple times. Something like this: (`switch` is not required, you can use your `if else` construct)

```
int Variable;

if (scanf("%d",&Variable) != 1) {
 // error handling
}


switch (Variable) {
  case 1:
    // code
    break;
  case 2:
    // code
    break;
  case 3:
    // code
    break;
  case 4:
    // code
    break;
  default:
    printf("Invalid Input\n");
}
```

A few extra points:

- don’t use floating points when integers will suffice. Floating points numbers have the problem of precision as you will surely find down the road. In your example since `Variable` can be only `1`, `2`, `3` or `4` you should definitely make it `int` (regardless if you use the `switch` which requires an integer data type or you use `if-else` who works with floating points also).
- upper case for variable names is less common (I am not saying don’t use this convention, I am just making you aware of this fact)
- favor clarity for your code, e.g. don’t use `variable - 4 == 0`, use `variable == 4`

Comment: I seem to get this error: error:                                 statement requires expression of integer type ('double' invalid)
switch (Variable) {
^       ~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.                                                       Does that mean I can't use doubles with switch?

Comment: I formatted my code like your format but when I enter inputs I have to enter them 2 times to get to the equation. eg to get mols i need to enter "4 [enter] 4" before it goes to it.

Comment: @Pyrons it shouldn’t do that. I can’t tell you what’s wrong without looking at your updated code. You can put it somewhere on the web like http://ideone.com/ so we don’t polute this question with debugging your code and I’ll look over it.

Comment: You forgot to remove the next `scanf`s. **That** is the exact function that "asks for input"; following the flow of your code, it indeed asks twice.

Comment: @Pyrons :)) Haha you made me crack up. The whole point was to not scanf every time. If you use the `switch` completely remove the `ifs`

Comment: @Bolov Feel like such an idiot now. It's all fixed :) In case you are worried http://ideone.com/G4GnDE

Comment: `Variable == 1;` is completely pointless. It compares `Variable` with `1` and it does **nothing** with that information. Remove these lines. The `switch` with its `cases` takes care of *comparing* `Variable` with those values. Read more about `switch` if you are unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use switch and case statements to meet your needs. In your above code, it is not possible to directly enter into particular operation.`scanf` is used in else if, so user need to feed the inputs many times to select particular operation. Assume, if you want to perform 4th operation & the input are 4, 4, 4,4.

Answer (score 0):

Scanf require input. Program goes sequentially first checks `if`with an input if false goes to elseif and again require an input. So you need to enter 3 3 times to execute third elseif. And better practice is to use integer values for your variable. I recommend switch instead of all this.